# How to calculate a value based on certain conditions in Scala

Tags: scala, if-statement, immutability, tail-recursion

I have implemented a recursive method to check if number of parenthesis in a string is valid or not. Here is the code

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    @tailrec
    def isValid(newChars: List[Char], difference: Int): Boolean = {
      if (newChars.isEmpty) difference == 0
      else if (difference < 0) false
      else {
        var newDifference = difference // Scala IDE gives warning here

        if (newChars.head == '(') newDifference = difference + 1
        else if (newChars.head == ')') newDifference = difference - 1

        isValid(newChars.tail, newDifference)
      }
    }

    isValid(chars, 0)
}
```

I tested the above code for the following test cases and it works fine So I am only looking for improving the if/else ladder.

```
println("Testing parenthesis balancing")
assert(balance("(Sachin is learning (scala) and (spark))".toList))
assert(!balance("(Invalid))(expression)".toList))
assert(balance("".toList))
assert(balance("()()".toList))
assert(!balance("{())}{()}".toList))
```

As mentioned in the code, Scala IDE complains on that line saying

> Avoid mutable local variables

I am not really sure how to compute the value of `newDifference` without using if/else. Other option I could see is directly call `isValid` method in if/else ladder with computed values of newDifference.

I am still learning Scala So I want to know what could be the best possible way to write this code without mutating the local variable (or any other warning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
val newDifference =
  if (newChars.head == '(') difference + 1
  else if (newChars.head == ')') difference - 1
  else difference;
```

as `if` in Scala is an expression, or use `match`, which would be considered more idiomatic in this case:

```
val newDifference = newChars.head match {
  case '(' => difference + 1
  case ')' => difference - 1
  case _   => difference
}
```

The whole function can be converted into a single `match` on `newChars`, but I'll leave that to you. See the first example [here](https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2012/09/20/what-is-scala-pattern-matching/) for some ideas.

Comment: +1 Your 2nd example, Match pattern looks really nice and this is what I was looking for. Thanks @Dogbert

Answer (score 3):

People use pattern match for that. That way you can avoid both mutable variables and the "if/else ladder", that makes for horrible "spaghetti code".

```
   def isValid(chars: List[Char], ps: Int = 0) = (chars, ps) match {
      case (Nil, _) => ps == 0
      case (_, _) if ps < 0 => false
      case ('(' :: tail, ps) => isValid(tail, ps + 1)
      case (')' :: tail, ps) => isValid(tail, ps - 1)
      case (_ :: tail, ps) => isValid(tail, ps)
   }
```

Comment: Great!! What an amendment to my initial code. Your answer is a great example of how match pattern can make spaghetti code. Thanks for making that point.